# How can i reverse a file line by line?

Tags: python

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and I just cant

I want to reverse a file that looks like this

```
Hello there
My name is
How are you
```

And by reversing it i mean I want it to look like this after

```
there Hello
is name My
you are How
```

I have tried with

```
 lines = []
with open('test.txt', "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('testrev.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in reversed(lines):
        f.write(line)
```

and by adding

```
f.write(line[::-1])
```

Im sorry but i just cannot figure this out and help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: Hint: don't read from and write to the file at the same time. Either user an other output file or read, process, reopen and write.

Comment: The duplicate discusses reversing the words, and not the letters, of a given line. The short-short version, in Python, is `" ".join(line.split()[::-1]) + "\n"`

Comment: @KlausD.: They are reading from one file, then writing to another file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the code you wrote but adjust the following:

```
with open('testrev.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        rev_line = reversed(line.split())
        f.write(" ".join(rev_line) + "\n")
```

This reverses the order of the words in each line while keeping the order of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

just making up the code you have written:

```
lines = []
with open('test.txt', "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('testrev.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(" ".join(reversed(line.split()))+"\n")
```

if you are using Python 3, the last line could look also like this:

```
        f.write(*reversed(line.split())+"\n")
```